# How does one have access to frame's document object from another frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, frames

Allright I have a page containing a frameset. One of these frames contains an asp page which contains a script written in javascript. **This script needs to be able to access the content of an asp page which is contained inside another frame (in the frameset).** Here's an example of the frameset code:

```
<frameset name="foo">
    <frame name="frame1" src="mydomain/path/of/the/page.asp">
    <frame name="frame2" src="mydomain/path/of/the/other/page.asp">
```

So basically **the script inside the page contained within frame1 tries to access the contents (more specifically tries to insert a DOM element) inside the page contained within frame2.**

Both frames are on the same domain (and subdomain), so **cross-scripting shouldn't be an issue**. I can't edit the code outside the script so I'm forced to use frames. Here's my current code :

```
//Ideally, I would like to make sure the page contained within frame2 is loaded before trying to access it's elements. I still need to figure that one out. 
$(document, window.parent).ready( function () {    
    //Assign id "foo" to frame2 using jQuery
    $('frame[name="foo"]', window.parent.document).attr("id", "foo"); 
    var doc;
    var testNode;
    var frmObj = window.parent.document.getElementById('foo'); 
    if (frmObj.contentDocument) { // DOM
        doc = frmObj.contentDocument;
    } 
    else if (frmObj.contentWindow) { // IE 
        doc = frmObj.contentWindow.document;
    }
    if (doc) {
        testNode = doc.createElement('div');
        testNode.Id = "testNode";
        doc.getElementByTagName('body').appendChild(testNode);
    }
});
```

The line containing getElementByTagName throws an error in IE 10 :

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementByTagName'

It seems that the document object don't have any method named getElementByTagName. In that case, one could say that the document object doesn't exist, which is absurd since I've tested it's existence before trying to call it's methods. Knowing all this, **how can we solve this issue?**

Notes :

- I can't test the issue with another browser since external codes needed by all the pages uses vbscript.
- id "foo" is successfully added to frame2.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frames are not supported in HTML5, and if you would have a proper documenttype declaration, you'd see a blank page.

Anyway, no need to use jQuery, this is much more simple: to `frameset` window you refer *always* with `top`, all frame windows you can catch with `top.frame_name` (`id` is not needed), no matter where you want to refer them. When you need a document, it's just right under `window` object. In your case: `top.frame1.document` or `top.document`.

Notice also, that `foo` is the name of the `frameset`, not any frame. Hence `$('frame[name="foo"]', window.parent.document).attr("id", "foo");` is not doing what you expect. (Or maybe just a typo in the post?)

This should do the job, though `top` might be ready for a long time before the `body` in `frame2` exists.

```
$(document, top).ready(function () {    
    var testNode,
        frmObj = top.frame2,
        doc = frmObj.document;
    if (doc) {
        testNode = doc.createElement('div');
        testNode.id = 'testNode';
        doc.body.appendChild(testNode);
    }
});
```

Comment: @OlivierBlanchard What's wrong? First you accepted the answer, the rejected it. If you have any further questions, please post a comment.

Comment: Sorry for teasing you Teemu, I've selected your post as the selected answer by error. Nevertheless, I also wanted to thank you for taking the time to response to my question. As I stated in my question, the id "foo" was successfully added to frame2. The selector's syntax should be allright since I select the frame which have the name "foo" among all frames and the context is the parent document of the page contained within the frame. After correcting a couple of errors in your code, it also worked. The only reason why I've re-flagged your answer as accepted is because of it's elegance.

Comment: @OlivierBlanchard LOL... There were no errors, it's completely valid JS to chain variable declarations with [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Actually it's [done anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) by the interpreter, and some JS guides are even recommending it as an only valid way to write functions.